# Add data to multidimensial array

Tags: php, arrays, database, merge, intersect

I have some problems with adding data to my array. My first data has some data like the following code:

```
array1
{projectId: 1, task: 1, hoursEstimated: 345},
{projectId: 1, task: 4, hoursEstimated: 274},
{projectId: 2, task: 1, hoursEstimated: 432},
{projectId: 2, task: 2, hoursEstimated: 347},
{projectId: 2, task: 4, hoursEstimated: 815},

array2
{projectId: 1, task: 1, totalHoursWorked: 145},
{projectId: 1, task: 2, totalHoursWorked: 234},
{projectId: 1, task: 3, totalHoursWorked: 283},
{projectId: 1, task: 4, totalHoursWorked: 174},
{projectId: 2, task: 1, totalHoursWorked: 205},
{projectId: 2, task: 2, totalHoursWorked: 153},
{projectId: 2, task: 3, totalHoursWorked: 634},
{projectId: 2, task: 4, totalHoursWorked: 815},
```

So what i want to do is: array2 has to do is match both the taskId and projectId of array 1 and append the data. So for the first element in de array it would have become this:

```
Array3
{projectId: 1, task: 1, hoursEstimated: 345, totalHoursWorked: 145}
etc..
```

Comment: Can you include your actual code for declaring the first two arrays please

Comment: Your array is not valid in PHP.

Comment: Oh, yes i know. It is a dummy database. I am not at my workcomputer, so i dont have access to the database. But my query will give this output.

So the the projectId and the task has to be the same in both arrays so it could be appended into the array. we have lots of projects and we use the same task for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($data1 as $key => &$value){
    foreach($data2 as $k => $v){
        if($v['projectId'] == $value['projectId'] && $v['task'] == $value['task']){
            $value['totalHoursWorked'] = $v['totalHoursWorked'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off your dummy values, you could just use `foreach` and use `&` reference to array one. Example:

```
$array1 = array(
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 1, 'hoursEstimated' => 345),
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 4, 'hoursEstimated' => 274),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 1, 'hoursEstimated' => 432),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 2, 'hoursEstimated' => 347),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 4, 'hoursEstimated' => 815),
);

$array2 = array(
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 1, 'totalHoursWorked' => 145),
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 2, 'totalHoursWorked' => 234),
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 3, 'totalHoursWorked' => 283),
    array('projectId' => 1, 'task' => 4, 'totalHoursWorked' => 174),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 1, 'totalHoursWorked' => 205),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 2, 'totalHoursWorked' => 153),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 3, 'totalHoursWorked' => 634),
    array('projectId' => 2, 'task' => 4, 'totalHoursWorked' => 815),
);

foreach($array1 as &$values) {
    foreach($array2 as $values2) {
        if($values['projectId'] == $values2['projectId'] && $values['task'] == $values2['task']) {
            $values['totalHoursWorked'] = $values2['totalHoursWorked'];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array1);
```

Should yield something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [projectId] => 1
            [task] => 1
            [hoursEstimated] => 345
            [totalHoursWorked] => 145
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [projectId] => 1
            [task] => 4
            [hoursEstimated] => 274
            [totalHoursWorked] => 174
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [projectId] => 2
            [task] => 1
            [hoursEstimated] => 432
            [totalHoursWorked] => 205
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [projectId] => 2
            [task] => 2
            [hoursEstimated] => 347
            [totalHoursWorked] => 153
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [projectId] => 2
            [task] => 4
            [hoursEstimated] => 815
            [totalHoursWorked] => 815
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try these ways:

```
foreach($array1 as &$arr1){    
    foreach($array2 as $arr2){
         if($arr1['projectId'] === arr2['projectId'] 
         && $arr1['task'] === $arr2['task']){
              $arr1['totalHoursWorked'] = $arr2['totalHoursWorked'];
         }
    }
}
//or
array_walk($array1,function($arr1){
    foreach($array2 as $arr2){
         if($arr1['projectId'] === arr2['projectId']
         && $arr1['task'] === $arr2['task']){
              $arr1['totalHoursWorked'] = $arr2['totalHoursWorked'];
         }
    }
});
print_r($array1);
```